# Migrate asterisk config files to database configuration

Tags: asterisk

Does anyone have documentation or tooling to help migrate from a config file based asterisk deployment to a database deployment?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an automated migration script, but the gist is that you make with an extconfig.conf file that maps a traditional config file name to a table name (and set of MySQL or ODBC/DB credentials), and then a set of tables with slightly normalized (but nearly line-for-line) equivalents to what would be in a local config file.  http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime has more.

Another way to do realtime database-backed call routing is using AGI or Fast AGI.  We recommend AGI to our Asterisk hosting customers because it decouples call routing logic from phone/PBX functionality, something that's not at all true with an Asterisk dialplan (Asterisk RealTime or not).  Your dialplan then uses the AGI command (with an agi:// URL) instead of calling embedded dialplan commands.

That also lets you write the call logic/routing in whatever programming language does the job best, which is rarely AEL.  help.cloudvox.com has a bunch more AGI docs.

Troy

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing and ended up writing my own quick and dirty script using Asterisk::config modules from CPAN, hope it saves sometime of somebody else:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Asterisk::config;

my $rc = new Asterisk::config(file=>$ARGV[0]);
my $cols="";
my $vals="";


$parsed = $rc->fetch_sections_hashref();

foreach my $sec (sort keys %{$parsed})
{
    $cols="name";
    $vals="'$sec'";
    while ( my ($c, $v) = each(%{$parsed->{$sec}}) )
    {
        $cols.= ",$c";
        $vals.= ",'".join(',',@{$v})."'";
    }
    print "insert into mytable($cols) values($vals);\n";
}
print "\n\n";
```